# Wrap text in span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to wrap some text in span depend on `data-text`.

For example, if I have this code:

```
<div data-text="world">Hello World We Love JavaScript</div>
```

I'd like to wrap it like this:

```
<div data-text="world">Hello <span>World</span> We Love JavaScript</div>
```

I have tried to solve this problem using jQuery's `replace()` method, but I have not yet found the right solution:

```js
$("div").text(function (index, text) {
    return text.replace($("div").data("text"), "<span>" + $("div").data("text") + "</span>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-text="Hello">Hello <span>World</span> We Love JavaScript</div>
```

Comment: Well, you already have the word "World" wrapped in your html. So text will just get the first *text* part. I suggest try with `html()`. You may of course need to check to ensure if isn't already wrapped though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) method with a callback and generate regex using the attribute value with [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)(to match only the exact word) to replace the word with wrapped span.

```js
$('div[data-text]').html(function(_, htm) {
  return htm.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + $(this).data('text') + '\\b', 'ig'), '<span>$&</span>')
})
```

```css
div span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-text="Hello|love">Hello World We Love JavaScript</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much it's what i need but if i'd like to wrap more one text for example if i need to wrap World Love

Comment: `data-text="Hello|love"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set html of element instead of text :

```
$("div").html(function(i,html) {
  return html.replace(/(World)/g, '<span>World</span>');
});
```

```js
$("div").html(function(i,html) {
  return html.replace(/(World)/g, '<span>World</span>');
});
```

```html
<style>span{color:red}</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-text="Hello">Hello <span>World</span> We Love JavaScript</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code http://jsfiddle.net/wQns7/2138/

```
$("div").html(function () {
   return $(this).html().replace("World", "<span>World</span>"); 
});​​​​​
```

​

Comment: Welcome Mohamed